# what's the purpose of this code? is it counting number of digits?

Tags: c++, c

```
   if ((16 << (int)(4*((num.length()-2)-i))) == 0)
```

What does it mean? Is it a bit manipulation? It could be written much more simpler if it's only counting the digits, this is why I thought it might be something different than what I know.

Comment: google for *bit shifting*

Comment: start evaluating inside-out. try to break it down, will be easier to understand. :)

Comment: What is `num.length()`? A function on a `struct`? A class? (In that case suggesting the C tag is wrong!)

Comment: Beside the bit-shift in there, which people here have already explained, I'd say this is just a piece of obfuscated code that could have been written in a much easier to read way.

Answer (score 4):

`<<` is the left shift operator. Shifting left by `n`is the same as multiplying by 2 `n` times. If you shift far enough, all set bits will "fall over the edge" and the result will be `0`.

`16 << n` will become `0` if `n > sizeof(int)* BITS_PER_CHAR - 4`.

So the expression can be written as:

```
if ((sizeof(int) * BITS_PER_CHAR - 4) < (int)(4*((num.length()-2)-i))
```

`BITS_PER_CHAR` is 8 on any POSIX-compliant system. `sizeof(int)*BITS_PER_CHAR` is usually `32`, but can be other values.

Comment: Typo: `sizeof(int)` is usually 4.

Comment: `CHAR_BIT` from `limits.h`/`climits` is the portable way to write `BITS_PER_CHAR`